# Can't render a Tiled Map in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been trying to render a tiled map  to my LibGDX project but nothing shown on the screen, I followed this tutorial from here http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/16/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-1-Simple-Orthogonal-Maps.aspx.

Could the problem be that I didn't set the position of the camera right?

This is my code

```
  package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.AtlasTmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class Level extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
    ActorDemo jet;
    Stage stage;
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    AtlasTmxMapLoader test;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        jet = new ActorDemo();
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.addActor(jet);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,w/2,h/2);
        camera.update();
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("Level.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();

        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera.combined,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT)
            camera.translate(-32,0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){

            camera.position.x -=2;

        }
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT)
            camera.translate(32,0);
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.UP)
            camera.translate(0,-32);
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.DOWN)
            camera.translate(0,32);
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.NUM_1)
            tiledMap.getLayers().get(0).setVisible(!tiledMap.getLayers().get(0).isVisible());
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.NUM_2)
            tiledMap.getLayers().get(1).setVisible(!tiledMap.getLayers().get(1).isVisible());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the Desktop configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4KTs.png)

[Here is where I put my tiled map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhxB5.png)

[This is the tile set I used to create my tmx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3UGP.png)

I added this tile set to to the tiled map editor and created a tile sheet and then put it in my project

Comment: This code works for me just fine, except without the `jet` actor  and with my own map. Try the tilesheet from the tutorial. If you have any errors or output - please post it here

Comment: I did use the tilesheet used in the tutorial, and the same problem just a black screen, how did you use the tilesheet in the tutorial i may use it wrongly. thanks extenza for replying

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code to my ide and changed the filename. How about keys up, down, right, left, num_1, num_2 do they change anything?

Comment: they don't change anything just a black screen and no responses to any input, did the code work with you ?

Comment: Yes, it works. Could you please provide the whole file code?

Comment: then could it be a problem with the tilesheet i used?

Comment: and this is the whole file code.

Comment: i saved the tilesheet image from here http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/15/A-quick-look-at-Tiled-An-open-source-2D-level-editor.aspx and added it to the tileed map editor

Comment: No, it's not full code.. I don't see imports and class declaration. Create a new project (the whole project, not just a class) from scratch, and copy-paste the code from the tutorial. Don't forget to save it and make sure you're actually launching new code (not something old you were playing around before)

Comment: Now i edited the code above, you can see the whole file code

Comment: The code works for me. How do you launch your game? Is it desktop? Could you please post your launch configurations (screenshot I guess would be the easiest way) and `DesktopLauncher.java`?

Comment: I am using desktop launcher, and i uploaded a screen shot of the configuration

Comment: Create a new super simple tilesheet with monotone colour and try with it. If doesn't work - provide your tilesheet, so I can test it.

Comment: Didn't work , i just added the tileset i used, and how i added it to libgdx

Comment: Works in my machine, does not work on my machine. Sounds like there isn't so much problem with the code or tileset and more with the setup in the IDE which is causing the assets of the android module to not be found in the desktop module. <-- that's a wicked guess on my part based on what I see happening.

Comment: What ide do you use ? , i use intellij, i will see what i can do to solve it, thanks exenza

Comment: It worked, the problem was that the program was not able find the tile sheet , so I changed the path(from the .tmx file) to where it actually located and it worked.

Comment: Pleased you found an answer! Would you add that below, so that it can be easily seen by future readers with the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, the problem was that the program was not able to find the tile Set, so I changed the path(from the .tmx file) to where it actually located and it worked.